# How to Insert a Button into a HTML Table Cell

Tags: html, dom, html-table

I am creating a table using DOM. I want to insert a 'delete' button for every row. What I have attempted deletes my entire table. Where do I create the button element?

```
    function MakeTable(iArray)
   {
          var myArray = [];
           var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
          var button = document.createElement("button");

    for(var i = 0; i< iArray.length; ++i)
    {
        myArray[i] = iArray[i];
        let row0 = table.insertRow();
        let blankCell = row0.insertCell(0)
        let cell0 = row0.insertCell(1);
        let cell1 = row0.insertCell(2);
        let cell2 = row0.insertCell(3);
        blankCell.createElement("button"); 
        cell0.textContent = myArray[i].userID;
        cell1.textContent = myArray[i].username;
        cell2.textContent = myArray[i].password;
    }

document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(table);
```

}

Comment: `document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(table);`? Are you trying to append the table to itself? I don’t see anything that attempts to delete things in your code. Show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly this gives you a working example

```
<table id="myTable">

</table>

<script>
    let tr = document.createElement("TR");
    let td1 = document.createElement("TD");
    let td2 = document.createElement("TD");
    let td = document.createElement("TD");
    let button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    let node = document.createTextNode("Button Title");

    button.appendChild(node);
    td.appendChild(button);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(tr);

</script>

<style>

    td {
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 75px;
    }


</style>
```